# iOS: Removing one view from superview causes another to get removed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is a very odd problem. I have 5 subviews added to a `UIViewController`. One of them needs to be removed, but when I do this, one of the remaining 4 subviews is also removed. This necessitates that I re-add it using addSubview. The two views in question are not related in any way.

Is this a known `iOS SDK` bug? It happens for sure running on the simulator with iOS 6.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Put your code else its not possible to debug!

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't accidentally make this view that disappears, a subview of the one you're removing?

Comment: which method did you use to remove subview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here, In Your Question not mention That which Method you use for remove subView so,I give you simple suggestion for remove subView.**

Give `Tag` of Each `subView` such like,

```
self.subView1.tag = 1;
self.subView2.tag = 2;
.
.
.
.
self.subViewN.tag = N;
```

And You can access(*Remove*) any `subView` base on its `Tag`,  such like

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
```

**This tips might helpful for you.**

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `single subview` using the following code.

```
  [subview_Name removeFromSuperview];
```

if you want to remove `all subviews` form the view then use this.

```
  NSArray *subViewArray = [self.view subviews];
  for (id obj in subViewArray)
  {
   [obj removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

if you want to remove `all subview of particular class` then use this.

```
  NSArray *subViewArray = [self.view subviews];
  for (id obj in subViewArray)
  {
   if([obj isKindOfClass:[classname class]])
      {
          [obj removeFromSuperview];
      }

  }
```

example : if you want to `remove subview` of `UIImageView` class then replace `if` condition with this.

```
[obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]
```